# Text in window in macOS Catalina is blurry after sleep

Tags: mac, macos-catalina

After I updated my MacBook Pro to Catalina, every time I close the lid for a while some windows will be blurry.

Here is an example:

- The left window was opened before sleep and now it is blurry.
- The right one is newly opened.

This often happens when using Chrome and VScode.

Does anyone know this issue?

[image: Example: the left window was is opened before sleep and now it is blurry. The right one is newly opened.]

Comment: Does this happen for all apps or just VSCode? I suspect it's just VSCode and it's just a bug in whatever non-native cross-platform GUI toolkit Microsoft used.

Comment: This also happens in other apps, specifically Chrome for me.

Comment: I have the same problem. Chrome, Spotify and other apps got affected.

Comment: It seems as this problem affects all Chromium based applications: Chrome as a browser and Spotify & VSCode as Electron apps.

Comment: The fact that it shows in a screenshot would seem to indicate an issue with the video kext - id talk to Apple about it and see if maybe you’ve got a weird hardware issue or see if it’s a known problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is (related to?) a [chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1021340&can=1&q=catalina%20fuzzy&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) that's been fixed for version 79 (in beta at time of writing). Not sure how long it'll take to filter down to the electron apps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an external monitor? Maybe through an HDMI Cable etc.?

If yes, it can sometimes happen that the display resolution or DPI (Dots per Inch) in your display settings changes or gets modofied.

Just make sure there is not magnifacation taking place, and you are at the optimal screen-resolution. Let me know if any of these suggestions worked.

Kind regards,

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1220475)